# Access Environment Variables in PyTest Using os.environ.getenv and not an ini or env File

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, environment-variables, pytest

Apologies in advance if this is a bit rambly, but I am exhausted from trying to figure this out for the past few hours.

I am currently trying to use PyTest along with the Visual Studio Code Test Explorer with a PyTest configuration. I am setting my environment variables inside of my terminal using a separate script that pulls secrets from Amazon Parameter Store and stores them inside of my terminal as an environment variable.

However, PyTest is unable to "see" my environment variables as set by my script and my variables that contain my environment variables are just returning NoneType.

If I do not use PyTest, the environment variables are picked up easily as I just make calls to `os.environ.get`, and it works perfectly to retrieve the environment variables.

I have seen a variety of ways to set environment variables inside of PyTest, but they usually involve using an .ini file or a .env file which requires hardcoding the values of the environment variables into those files.

Is there a way to say "Hey PyTest, I know that you don't like `os.environ.get`, but I promise that those environment variables will exist at runtime." I phrase it this way because it's like PyTest cannot see any environment variables that exist in the system at runtime and must be manually told that the variables exist in a .env file (where you have to hardcode sensitive information).

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `pytest-env`? -- https://github.com/MobileDynasty/pytest-env

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I asked my question a different way here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72619729/vscode-test-explorer-pytest-inject-environment-variables-using-aws-parameter-sto

Answer (score 0):

pytest works with environment variables just fine. Consider this simple test:

```
import os


def test_env():
    assert os.environ.get("MYVAR") == "expected_value"
```

If run `pytest` without `MYVAR` in my environment, I get:

```
$ pytest
...
test_envvar.py F                                                                                [100%]

=============================================== FAILURES ================================================
_______________________________________________ test_env ________________________________________________
test_envvar.py:5: in test_env
    assert os.environ.get("MYVAR") == "expected_value"
E   AssertionError: assert None == 'expected_value'
...
```

But if I set it *in the environment in which pytest is runnig*, the test passes:

```
$ export MYVAR=expected_value
$ pytest
...
test_envvar.py .                                                                                [100%]

=========================================== 1 passed in 0.01s ===========================================
```

If you're not seeing the expected values for your environment variables, that suggests you're not setting them in the right place.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually asked my question in a better way here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72619729/vscode-test-explorer-pytest-inject-environment-variables-using-aws-parameter-sto

Comment: In the future, it's better to edit your question rather than posting what is effectively a duplicate.