# VSCode Test Explorer Pytest Inject Environment Variables using AWS Parameter Store

Tags: visual-studio-code, environment-variables, test-explorer

I am currently Using Pytest though the Python Test Explorer (see screen). I would like to pass my tests some environment variables at runtime. However, I currently get my AWS Parameter Store BEFORE I run tests. Meaning, I run a command in BASH that loads my environment variables into my current terminal session. Then I can run my test from the command line using `pytest exampletest.py`, and it finds the environment variable perfectly.

Trying to run `exampletest.py` from the integrated VSCode Test Explorer results in an error telling me that it could not find my environment variable. This means that whatever environment that is used when you hit the "Play Button" on the Test Explorer is not the same terminal session that I set my environment variables in.

The conventional way of setting environment variables such that they can be accessed when using the Test Explorer in VSCode is by either using an `ini` file or a `.env` file. The only caveat there is that you must hardcode the key value pair. I would not like to hardcode anything, as I would just like to inject them in at runtime from aws Parameter Store.

I really would like to continue using the Test Explorer to run my tests, as it has been great in the past, but if I cannot find a way to somehow get the Test Explorer to use my environment variables without using an `ini` or a `.env` file, I may have to abandon it.

Some questions:

1. When you click the play button on the Test Explorer to execute a test or suite of tests, what exactly happens? Does it open a Terminal session? Can you access that terminal session before runtime?
2. How does the Test Explorer set environment variables. When I `raise Exception(os.environ)`, I can see all the environment variables that are quite different from the ones that I get when I run from the command line.
3. Is there a way to say "Hey Test Explorer, please run the tests inside of this specified Terminal window that is already running"
4. Perhaps a virtual environment is a way to go (not really a question more of a thought). Doing some cursory research reveals more headaches to come if I pursue this route I believe.
5. Do you have any further reading about that VsCode Test Explorer that goes beyond the official documentation. I feel like I can make some changes to it's source code or something, but I feel like documentation on it is a bit lacking.

Let me know your thoughts on this matter, and thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Re: "see screen": what screen?

Comment: In what environment are you running VS Code? Linux/Windows/Mac OS? How are you starting it -- running `code` in the terminal, or clicking on an application icon?

Comment: I attached the screen that shows from where I am running the test. From inside Visual Studio code you hit the test beaker. Then you hit the play button (2nd screenshot). I am on a Macbook pro

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question. The only way I could make it work was by this unwieldy series of steps before running the tests via the vscode UI:

1. Execute your script or command in a terminal to set the env
   variables.
2. Copy those env variables into your .env file (placed at the root of your project/vscode-workspace). I usually do :
   `env | grep AWS_` or whatever you want and you'll see them as name-value pairs. I then copy and paste those entries at the bottom of the .env file each time I run the test via the UI.
3. Now execute your tests via the vscode UI (the test 'beaker'/flask). The testing UI/flask seems to execute the .env file every time before it runs the tests and hence picks up those env variables.

I know, it's not preferable - you would want it to just pick it up from the env values you see in your integrated terminal but so far that is not happening.